# Accessing script scope variables from loaded vimscript file

Tags: vim

Here is a scenario:

I would like to load another vimscript file into my script(via :runtime! command), and have access to script scoped (s:) variables and functions that are inside loaded file.

Is it possible (without altering file that is loaded)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the script exposes a function for that purpose, I'm afraid that it won't be possible to access script variables.

For instance, all my autoload plugins have a function such as

```
function! lh#dict#debug(expr) abort
  return eval(a:expr)
endfunction
```

However, it's perfectly possible to access script function through a very dirty trick.

But, honestly, you'd better ask the script maintainer to open his/her script for your need(s). You need first to obtain the script id (this can be done by parsing the result of `:scriptname` through `:redir` command or through the recent `execute()` function.

```
" or if your prefer, if you're looking plugin foobar.vim:
let snr = matchstr(matchstr(split(execute('scriptnames'), "\n"), 'foobar.vim'), '^\d\+')
```

Let's suppose the 42nd script loaded defines the function `s:foo()`, you can access to it with:

```
let Foo = function('<SNR>42_foo') " or, use snr variable obtained as explained above instead of 42
echo Foo(42)
```

Comment: Thanks Luc, I will try this later. Not sure if asking maintainer will be possible, as the file I'm loading is .indent/html.vim.

Comment: @kam, you mean this is a standard file? The procedure is to contact its maintainer with your patch. He'll then send the file back to Bram.

Comment: I've found that `'\(^\s*\)\@<=\d\+'` works better than `'^\d\+'` because there may be leading whitespace.